# PHP Get Element From Each File in Folder

Tags: php, html, dom

Add file titled index.php in your folder and paste the below in there.  Now you can grab content from all the other .php files in the folder by ID.  Sorts by date.  You're welcome.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<?php include('../includes/head.php'); ?>
<body>
    <?php include('../includes/header.php'); ?>
    <div id="push"></div>
    <div id="main">
        <?php

        function innerHTML(DOMNode $node) { 
          $innerHTML = ''; 
          $children  = $node->childNodes;
        foreach($children as $child) { 
            $innerHTML .= $node->ownerDocument->saveHTML($child);
        }
          return $innerHTML;
        }                   

        $filename = glob("*.php");
        $filename = array_diff($filename, array('index.php',));
        function sort_by_mtime($file1,$file2) {
            $time1 = filemtime($file1);
            $time2 = filemtime($file2);
            if ($time1 == $time2) {
                return 0;
            }
            return ($time1 < $time2) ? 1 : -1;
            }
        usort($filename,"sort_by_mtime");
        foreach ($filename as &$value) {
            $doc = new DOMDocument();
            $doc->loadHTMLFile($value);
            $whatYouWant = $doc->getElementById('thisDiv');

            echo innerHTML($whatYouWant);
            }  
        ?>
    </div>
    <?php include('../includes/footer.php'); ?>
<div id="alertWindow"></div>
</body></html>
```

Comment: This is not really a question isn't it?

Comment: You are correct.  I did not post in the form of a question.  I just posted an answer.  ...Just trying to help.  I will be sure and post questions only in future.

Comment: No need for that. Post a question and answer it by yourself. Also you will get a badge for that :)